# How to change the starting page of Windows 8 app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to change the starting page of my app. Instead of Page1.xaml I want page2.xaml to open by default when the app starts. Is there any way to do this??

Comment: You need to change the page referenced in the OnLaunched event , see code sample here:
[sample](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/how-change-start-page-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/613f220e-cce3-40f4-8aed-7522986ac795). You have to change it in the `App.xaml.cs` in the `OnLaunched` method

Regards.